# Trigonometric equation.

Tags: trigonometry

Please help in Solving the Trigonometric Equation:

$$\cos^2x - \sin^2x = \cos3x$$

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried so far? This makes it easier to give a satisfactory answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
\cos^2x-\sin^2x &= \cos3x\\
\cos2x &= \cos3x\\
2x &= 2\pi n\pm 3x\\
x &= 2\pi n \text{ or } x=\frac{2\pi n}{5}
\end{align*}$$
where $n\in\mathbb Z$.

@ThomasAndrews: The second case includes the first case. $2\pi n=\frac{2\pi(5n)}5$.

Comment: The second case, note, includes the first case. $2\pi n = \frac{2\pi(5n)}{5}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's true.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cos 3x=\cos x \cos x - \sin x \sin x= \cos 2x,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
3x\pm 2x = 2k\pi
$$
for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the trigonometry identity for the $\cos 2\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x = \cos 3x$$

Now Using the formula $\cos2x = \cos^2 x-\sin^2 x$

So $$\cos 2x = \cos 3x\Rightarrow \cos3x  = \cos 2x\Rightarrow 3x = 2n\pi\pm 2x$$

Where $n\in \mathbb{Z}\;,$ above we have used the formula $$\cos x = \cos \alpha \;,$$ Then $x=2n\pi\pm \alpha\;,$ Where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

So Solutions are $3x = 2n\pi+2x$ or $3x = 2n\pi-2x$$

So we get $x=2n\pi$ or $\displaystyle x = \frac{2n\pi}{5}\;,$ Where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

So Final Solution is $\displaystyle x= \frac{2n\pi}{5}\;,$

Comment: Oh yes Thanks Thomas Andrews

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you should be after the roots of $\cos(3x)-\cos(2x)=0$. To continue from here you may use the identity $\cos \theta-\cos \alpha=-2\sin\frac{\theta-\alpha}{2}\sin\frac{\theta+\alpha}{2}$, i.e.

$$\cos(3x)-\cos(2x)=-2\sin\frac{5x}{2}\sin\frac{x}{2}$$